# Oracle search text of views

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have over 1000 views and I want to run a search which will display the names of the views containing the string `abc` in its SQL. How do I search all stored procedures/SQL including that of my views? When I run the command:

```
SELECT *
FROM   all_source
WHERE  text LIKE '%abc%'
```

it returns me source code in which the string `abc` is present. But this does not include views.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This gets easier in 12c, where you can use

```
select *
from   all_views v
where  lower(v.text_vc) like '%abc%';
```

This assumes the text string you are looking for is in the first 4000 characters. You might also have the report include any view where `text_length` is > 4000 along with a warning.

In earlier versions (or to avoid the 4000 character restriction), you might try a PL/SQL loop like this:

```
begin
    dbms_output.put_line('Owner                          View name');
    dbms_output.put_line('------------------------------ -------------------------------');

    for r in (
        select v.owner, v.view_name, v.text
        from   all_views v
        where  v.owner <> 'SYS'
    )
    loop
        if lower(r.text) like '%abc%' then
            dbms_output.put_line(rpad(r.owner,31) || r.view_name);
        end if;
    end loop;
end;
```

PL/SQL implicitly converts the SQL `LONG` value to a 32K PL/SQL string.

(In my tests in 12.2.0.1.0, this failed with `ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error` at the `select` statement when my cursor included `SYS.DBA_SCHEDULER_RUNNING_JOBS` or `SYS."_user_stat"`, even though other views with longer text were handled successfully, and I'm not sure why. There may be some issue with this I'm not seeing.)

Answer (score 4):

Select `ALL_VIEWS` instead (column name is `TEXT` as well).

Though, you'd rather use one of `UPPER` or `LOWER` functions as

```
select *
from all_views
where lower(text) like '%abc%'
```

because once you might have put it as 'abc', another time 'ABC', etc.

**[EDIT, because of ORA-00932]**

Oh, yes - in ALL_VIEWS, the TEXT column is of a LONG datatype (while in ALL_SOURCE it is a VARCHAR2, so LIKE won't work on ALL_VIEWS.

One option is to create a "temporary" table which contains all views & apply the TO_LOB function on the TEXT column, and then select from it:

```
SQL> create or replace view my_emp as select empno, ename xxx_ename, job from emp;

View created.

SQL> create table my_all_views as
  2  select owner, view_name, to_lob(text) text
  3  from all_views;

Table created.

SQL> select owner, view_name
  2  from my_all_views
  3  where lower(text) like '%xxx%';

OWNER                          VIEW_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
SYS                            USER_SCHEDULER_JOB_DESTS
SYS                            ALL_SCHEDULER_JOB_DESTS
SYS                            USER_XML_SCHEMAS
SYS                            ALL_XML_SCHEMAS
SYS                            ALL_XML_SCHEMAS2
SCOTT                          MY_EMP

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Its drawback is that it doesn't scale; if you create a new view, you'll have to recreate the table.

Or, you could create your own function which would do that search. For example:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_search_view (par_string in varchar2)
  2    return sys.odcivarchar2list
  3    pipelined
  4  is
  5  begin
  6    for cur_r in (select view_name, text from all_views
  7                  where text_length < 32767)
  8    loop
  9      if instr(cur_r.text, par_string) > 0 then
 10         pipe row(cur_r.view_name);
 11      end if;
 12    end loop;
 13
 14    return;
 15  end;
 16  /

Function created.

SQL> select * from table(f_search_view('xxx'));

COLUMN_VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
USER_XML_SCHEMAS
ALL_XML_SCHEMAS
ALL_XML_SCHEMAS2
MY_EMP

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried running this. Got the error: ORA00932-inconsistent datatypes: expected char got long. Any idea why?

Comment: I edited my message by adding some examples; have a look.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It works using the first method.